# MySqlCommand: no rows returned

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database created in a server and I added a row by MySql query browser for testing. This row is visible either with PhpMyAdmin or MySql query browser.

But when I want to reach this table within my program it says me there is no rows (`reader.HasRows = false`)

cs is the connection string in `PublicVariables` class

Here is the code

```
public static int checkuser(string myuser, string mypass)
{
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
            {
                string MypassMd5 = MakeMD5(mypass);
                conn.Open();

                if (conn == null)
                    Environment.Exit(0);

                using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                 new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password " + "FROM Users WHERE username = 'myuser'" ,conn))
                {                        
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //DateTime mytime = DateTime.Now  ;
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            if (Convert.ToString(reader["password"]) != MypassMd5)
                            {
                                reader.Close();
                                conn.Close();
                                return -1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PublicVariables.UserId = Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);
                                PublicVariables.UserDegre = Convert.ToInt16(reader["userdegre"]);
                                conn.Close();
                                reader.Close();
                                return 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                            conn.Close();
                            return 2;
                        }
                 }
            }            
       }
   }
   catch (MySqlException ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Please tell me you're using something more secure than MD5 for the password hash? MD5 is incredibly weak for this.

Comment: @Joel I will use another crypto instead of MD5 but as i am translating an old program written in turbo pascal and as it's in my old programme i used this for instance but i think use shasum or Bcrypt as suggested by you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the primary error is in your command string , `myuser` is a variable and you cannot pass its value putting the variable name inside quotes.

```
new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = 'myuser'" ,conn)
```

instead this line should be converted to use a parameterized query

```
string commandText = "SELECT username, password, userdegre FROM Users WHERE username = @uname"; 
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText ,conn)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", myuser);
    ....
```

Looking at your code you have another error after this. You try to read the field `userdegre`, but this field is not retrieved by your query, so you need to add it to the list of retrieved fields.
But the only field you really need to know is `userdegre` because you already know the username and the password, so you could remove the datareader and use ExecuteScalar and pass the username and the password as parameters for the WHERE clause. If you get anything in return then you are sure that your user is authenticated by the database.

```
string commandText = "SELECT userdegre FROM Users WHERE username = @uname AND Password =@pwd";
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand( commandText ,conn))
{                        
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", myuser);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", MypassMd5);
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null)
    {
          PublicVariables.UserId = myuser;
          PublicVariables.UserDegre = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't check `reader.HasRows`. You need to call `reader.Read()`, and check the result of that.

Also, some side issues:

1. MD5 is incredibly weak for a password hash. Really. Just don't use it for that. Look into bcrypt as a *much* better alternative. Better still if you're not writing authentication code yourself at all. Look for a library for help to get this stuff right... it's just so easy to write authentication code that *seems* to work, passes all your tests, but has a subtle flaw that gets you hacked a few months down the road.
2. No need to call `conn.Close()`. That's what your `using` blocks are for. They *will* handle this for you.
3. I'd remove the try/catch as well. Since you're already returning error conditions to the calling code, I'd leave that as the place where errors are processed, such that your try/catch should go at that level.
4. You're looking for `userdegre` in the results that was not in the select list.
5. Parameterized queries are your friend.

Put it all together you and you end up with this:

```
public static int checkuser(string myuser, string mypass)
{
    string passHash = BCrypt(mypass); //Need to get bcyrpt library and make the function
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
    using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                 new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password, userdegre FROM Users WHERE username = @user" ,conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = myuser;
        conn.Open();

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!reader.Read()) return 2;
            if (Convert.ToString(reader["password"]) != MypassMd5) return -1;

            PublicVariables.UserId = Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);
            PublicVariables.UserDegre = Convert.ToInt16(reader["userdegre"]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password, userdegre " + "FROM Users WHERE username = @user" ,conn)) //This is not working


 new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password, userdegre FROM Users WHERE username = @user" ,conn)) //This WORKS!

@Steve thanks for illumination for redefining myuser variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this  `new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password, userdegre  " + "FROM Users WHERE username = 'myuser'" ,conn))`
adding userdegre the column name in your select statement.

Comment: Finally for c# 2008 net 3.5 working copy of this after the help of @Joel and @ Steve is as this:

Answer (score 0):

Finally for c# 2008 net 3.5 WORKING COPY of this after the help of @Joel and @ Steve is as this:

public static int usertrue(string myuser, string mypass)

```
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(PublicVariables.cs))
            {
                string MypassMd5 = MakeMD5(mypass);

                using (MySqlCommand cmd =
                 new MySqlCommand("SELECT username, password ,userdegre FROM Users WHERE username =  @user",conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = myuser;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        if (!reader.Read()) return 2;
                        if (Convert.ToString(reader["password"]) != MypassMd5)  return -1;                            {
                        PublicVariables.UserId = Convert.ToString(reader["username"]);
                        PublicVariables.UserDegre = Convert.ToInt16(reader["userdegre"]);
                        return 1;
                     }


                 }
            }            

            }
        }
```